# Add dark overlay to div on hover

Tags: html, css

I have several div elements with content and I want to add dark overlay on hover.

My html code:

```
<div class="main-slider">
    <div class="owl-item">
        <li class="dark-overlay">
            //content
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <li class="dark-overlay">
            //content
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <li class="dark-overlay">
            //content
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

So I try to use css:

```
.dark-overlay{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  text-align:center;
  padding:45px 0 66px 0;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.main-slider li:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. Only a `ul` can be the parent of an `li` element.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNRZEz

Comment: what you have does work. When the elements are hovered over, they get a dark background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `li` in `div` so I replaced them with `div`. I don't know what you want it to look like, but this definitely adds a dark overlay on hover - you just can't see them until they are hovered over.

Unless you explain more what you're expecting, we won't be able to help you.

```css
.dark-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0 66px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.main-slider div.dark-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-slider">
  <div class="owl-item">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```